# Use npm module with cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, npm

I created a cordova project following [this tutorial](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface).

I want to include packages (e.g. coffee-script) using a package.json and npm.

What's the recommended way to achieve this?